# On Pidgin, how to search for the next person with a name?

Tags: search, contacts, pidgin, gtk

In the contact list, when I type a name, it highlights the first match. How to find the second match? I tried <kbd>F3</kbd> with no avail.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the <kbd>↑</kbd> <kbd>↓</kbd>  arrow keys.

Comment: I keep pressing *Enter* :P